# Change screen from main menu to game

Tags: android, libgdx, menu

I'd like to know how I can change the screen from the Main Menu to the Game itself but im having quite the trouble and I would appreciate the help. What I want to do is when I press *btn.Play* it changes the screen from the main menu to the game.

Here's the code I got (sorry it's long):

Game:

```
@Override
public void create(){

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

    Up = new Texture("left.png");

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false,1280,720);

    //creates the square in the middle of the screen
    square = new Rectangle();
    square.x = 630;
    square.y = 720 / 2 - 32 /2;
    square.width = 32;
    square.height = 32;

    //code
}

//code

public void render() {

    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    cam.update();

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(Up, square.x, square.y);
    //code
    batch.end();
}
```

Screens (used to display the first screen) :

```
public class Screens extends com.badlogic.gdx.Game {


//creates the timing on the splash screen


@Override
public void create() {

    startTime = TimeUtils.millis();

    //sets the next screen as the splash screen
    setScreen( new SplashScreen(this));
}

@Override
public void render(){

    super.render();
    rendCount++;
}

@Override
public void dispose(){

    endTime = TimeUtils.millis();
}
```

SplashScreen:

```
public class SplashScreen implements Screen  {


public SplashScreen(Game g) {

    myGame = g;

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 1280, 720);
}


@Override
public void show() {


    //image of the splash screen
    splashTexture = new Texture("splash.jpg");

    //timer starts
    timeStart = TimeUtils.millis();
}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    SpriteBatch batch = new SpriteBatch();

    //draws the image on screen
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(splashTexture, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
    rendCounter++;

    // if the timer is higher than 5 secs goes to the main screen
    if(TimeUtils.millis() > (timeStart+5000)) {
        myGame.setScreen(new MainScreen());
    }

}

@Override
public void dispose(){

    splashTexture.dispose();

}
```

Main Menu:

```
public class MainScreen implements Screen{

private SpriteBatch batch;
private OrthographicCamera cam;
private Stage stage;
private TextButton btnPlay, btnExit;
private BitmapFont font;
private Skin skin;
private TextureAtlas atlas;

public MainScreen() {

    cam = new OrthographicCamera();
    cam.setToOrtho(false, 1280,720);
    batch = new SpriteBatch();

}


@Override
public void show() {

    // creates the pack for the buttons, its skin, the font used on the buttons, and the stage(screen)

    atlas = new TextureAtlas("buttons.pack");
    skin = new Skin();
    skin.addRegions(atlas);
    font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("font.fnt"), false);

    stage = new Stage();
    stage.clear();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    // sets the style of the buttons

    TextButton.TextButtonStyle style = new TextButton.TextButtonStyle();
    style.up = skin.getDrawable("btn_up");
    style.down = skin.getDrawable("btn_down");

    // sets the font of the buttons

    style.font = font;


    //creates the play button with the text, its position and the size

    btnPlay = new TextButton("Play", style);
    btnPlay.setSize(350, 150);
    btnPlay.setPosition(450, 400);

        btnPlay.addListener(new InputListener() {

            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

                new Game()
                dispose();

            }
        });

    btnExit = new TextButton("Exit", style);
    btnExit.setSize(350,150);
    btnExit.setPosition(450, 150);

    btnExit.addListener(new InputListener() {

        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            return true;
        }

        public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {

            Gdx.app.exit();
            dispose();

        }
    });

    stage.addActor(btnPlay);
    stage.addActor(btnExit);

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {

    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

    stage.act();

    batch.begin();
    stage.draw();
    batch.end();

}

@Override
public void dispose() {
    batch.dispose();
    stage.dispose();
    atlas.dispose();
    skin.dispose();
    font.dispose();

}
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925054/mvc-pattern-in-android

Comment: `((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MyScreen());`

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this that's quite easy is to let there be a single class that extends `Game`, that launches the first `Screen` (this is pretty much what you have).

What you also need to do though is to pass a reference to that `Game` to all your `Screen`s so that they can call `setScreen` themselves when they want to go to another screen.

In a somewhat simplified example the root would the the `Game` class, in your code this is `Screens`;

```
package com.androidstudiosandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;

public class MyAndroidStudioSandboxGame extends Game {
  @Override
    public void create () {
        setScreen(new SplashScreen(this));
    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    }
}
```

As you can see, this calls `setScreen` in the `create` passing an instance to the `SplashScreen`;

```
package com.androidstudiosandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;

public class SplashScreen implements Screen {

    private Game game;
    private long showTime;

    public SplashScreen(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (TimeUtils.timeSinceMillis(showTime) > 2000) {
            game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void show() {
        showTime = TimeUtils.millis();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) { }

    @Override
    public void pause() { }

    @Override
    public void resume() { }

    @Override
    public void hide() { }

    @Override
    public void dispose() { }
}
```

As the `SplashScreen` has a reference to the initial `Game` instance, it can call `game.setScreen` when the time has elapsed and pass a new instance of a `MenuScreen` that also gets the `Game` instance passed;

```
package com.androidstudiosandbox;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.InputEvent;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Button;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton;
import com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.utils.ClickListener;

public class MenuScreen implements Screen {

    private final Stage stage;

    public MenuScreen(final Game game) {

        stage = new Stage();
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        TextButton button = new TextButton("My button", some_skin);
        button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                game.setScreen(new GameScreen(game));
            }
        });

        stage.addActor(button);
    }

    @Override
    public void show() { }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        stage.act(delta);

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) { }

    @Override
    public void pause() { }

    @Override
    public void resume() { }

    @Override
    public void hide() { }

    @Override
    public void dispose() { }
}
```

The `MenuScreen` sets up a `Stage` and a `TextButton` and wires up the click handler of the button to call `setScreen` when the button is pressed. Note that the `game` argument to the constructor needs to be `final` here as the click handler is a seperate class.

package com.androidstudiosandbox;

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Screen;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.TimeUtils;


public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    private Game game;

    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        this.game = game; // Store this to call game.setScreen(new MenuScreen(game)) to return to the menu
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Do game logic and rendering
    }

    @Override
    public void show() { }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) { }

    @Override
    public void pause() { }

    @Override
    public void resume() { }

    @Override
    public void hide() { }

    @Override
    public void dispose() { }
}
```

The actual game play is then handled by the `GameScreen`, this class also takes a reference to `Game` so that the player can return to the `MenuScreen` again (that part I've left out though).

Comment: You do not need to pass `Game` as a reference since the `ApplicationListener` can be accessed by `Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()` and casted as `Game`. So `((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new MyScreen());` would be enough whenever you want to change screen.

Comment: Yeah but Im getting this error: _com.mygdx.game.Screens cannot be cast to com.mygdx.game.Game_

Comment: @gafflx Don't cast it to your `Game` class, you need to cast it to the *libGDX* `Game` class.

Comment: @bornander like so: `public class Screens extends com.badlogic.gdx.Game` ?